# Creating two loaders for a website using conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having 2 different loaders for a website, i just need that when the users enter for the first time main website loader should appear else for the second visit the normal loader would appear.

The best reference would be the linkedin website.

Please can anyone help me to this?

Thanks

Comment: Please share your code with us.

Comment: Short answer: Cookies. Long answer. SO is not a code making site, you need to share the code you have tried to solve this issue

Comment: This is the link www.whitecloudsstudio.com/wcs where you can see the main loader to which i need only for the first time when the user visits. @LinkinTED

Comment: This is the link www.whitecloudsstudio.com/wcs where you can see the main loader to which i need only for the first time when the user visits. @MihaiT

Comment: that comment doesn't give us any info on what you have actually tried to solve this issue. The best answer i can give you is to use cookies. Search on the web for that

Answer (score 0):

You are asking how to know whether user sees the website for the first time or not. You can keep such data stored in the browser, and you can use that in a later session.

I am using [this w3schools article](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) for the examples.

set a cookie like this. `hasUserSeenPageBefore` is a custom variable. You can create whatever variable of any type.

```
document.hasUserSeenPageBefore = true;
```

and use it like a regular variable in javascript.

```
if(document.hasUserSeenPageBefore){
    //show regular logo
} else {
    //show the other logo
}
```

Comment: I am not asking about the user loggedIn i am asking about the visit of the user for the first time to appear the main loader only once.

Thanks for the reply! @nipunasudha

Comment: Edited the answer. you can store whatever variable in cookies, use your creative thinking and make use of that feature. Experiment with the code.

Comment: You are welcome, consider marking the answer if it helped :)